# Laravel validation unique on two columns

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-6

Below is the structure of my table:

corporations

- id
- uuid
- corporation_name

corp_branches

- id
- corp_id
- branch_name

The relationship is defined as Each corporations can have Many corp_branches but I want to have a check that branch_name under each corporations should be unique. Two different branches under different corporations can have the same name but two branches under one corporation cant have the same name.

I have tried this

```
'branch_name' => 'required|string|max:100|unique:corp_branches,branch_name,NULL,id,corp_id,'.$this->get('corp_id'),
```

Comment: Will you also be using these rules for updating a branch name as well?

Comment: No, I will be writing separate one for editing. These are for only creation.

Comment: Can you explain how the validation you have currently isn't working i.e. what isn't working that should be working and also what error message you're getting (if any).

Comment: Unique on two columns? It only `branch_name`

Comment: @rwd its not giving any error but its allowing me to have same branch name under one corporation

Comment: @WahyuKristianto yes in two coloumns like corp_id and branch_name combination should be unique in the table.

Comment: @dev.abhi.abik is your model `Corporation` and `CorpBranch`?

Comment: Is `corp_id` an input or part of the url? What do you get if you `dd($this->get('corp_id'))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
'branch_name' =>['required', 'unique:corp_branches,corp_id,'.$this->id.',NULL,corp_id,branch_name,'.$request->input('branch_name')]
```

Comment: can you give details about exception

Comment: First it throws exception for udefined variable '$request'
"message": "Undefined variable: request",
        "exception": "ErrorException",
so i changed the $request to $this, and still it throws the below exception

"message": "Undefined offset: 3",
        "exception": "ErrorException",
        "file": "/var/www/mydomain/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php",
        "line": 863

Answer (score 0):

You need [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

#### Step #1 - Generate a rule

```sh
php artisan make:rule UniqueBranch
```

#### Step #2 - Modify `app/Rules/UniqueBranch.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class UniqueBranch implements Rule
{
    protected $corp_id;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($corp_id)
    {
        $this->corp_id = $corp_id;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // Assume your model name is `Corporation`
        $corporation = Corporation::find($this->corp_id);

        if ($corporation) {
            $exists = $corporation
                ->corp_branches() // assume you have relation to braches
                ->where('name', $value)
                ->count();

            if (!$exists) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The branch name has already been taken.';
    }
}
```

#### Step #3 - Using `UniqueBranch`

```php
'branch_name' => [
    'required',
    'string',
    'max:100',
    new UniqueBranch($this->get('corp_id'))
]
```

Comment: can't we do it without creating any new rule.